# Overriding save() model method for permissions

Tags: django, methods, model, save, overriding

Am trying to override save() method so that only the creator and administrator are able to update the model field values as :

```
if not self.pk:
        super(Shastra, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
else:
        if (self.person == args[0].user) or (self.person.is_superuser):
            super(Shastra, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

While update am passing request to the save method as

```
 def edit(request, shastra_id):
    shastra_id = int(shastra_id)
    shastra = Shastra.objects.get(pk = shastra_id )
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_shastra_edit = ShastraEditForm(request.POST, instance = shastra)
        if form_shastra_edit.is_valid():
            form_shastra_edit.save(request)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/edited/successfully')
    else:
    form_shastra_edit = ShastraEditForm(instance = shastra)
```

But am getting " tuple index out of range " error . What is going wrong in this ?

Comment: I think args[0].user is as same as request.user since am passing "request" in save() . Please help

Comment: Let me know if i can clarify more on the question .

Comment: Show the whole `save` method, including the declaration.

Comment: " self.person == args[0].user " is causing some problem here .

Comment: Sigh. What is the definition of the save method? What is args?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use request in a Model.save() method. You have to do request-based validation in your views method (in your edit method for instance). The Model layer is unaware of 'request' objects..

Make your edit method something like:

```
def edit(request, shastra_id):
    shastra_id = int(shastra_id)
    shastra = Shastra.objects.get(pk = shastra_id )
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_shastra_edit = ShastraEditForm(request.POST, instance = shastra)
        if form_shastra_edit.is_valid() and shastra.user == request.user:
                form_shastra_edit.save(request)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/edited/successfully')
    else:
        form_shastra_edit = ShastraEditForm(instance = shastra)
```

Comment: Ya i can do that , but then again i also want that one superuser ( not the 'admin') other than the creator to edit the values . Do i need to put that check also in my view only ? Is there a way around to do validation in the model itself ?

Comment: You have to do that by changing the Shastra ModelAdmin. E.g. override ShastraModelAdmin.has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None) . See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods

Comment: The whole idea of the Model-View-Controller pattern (Django calls it Model-Template-View) is that the Model code is unaware/decoupled from the web layer. This provides "separation of concerns". Translating web-requests to users with permissions, and checking the permissions in the right (Django-)View code is the way to go. You could annotate your model classes with 'required permissions' data, but this should still be checked by your (Django)View code!